# When does Task.Run flow SynchronizationContext with ExecutionContext?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, synchronizationcontext

[This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/06/15/executioncontext-vs-synchronizationcontext.aspx) from states that `SynchronizationContext` may flow with `ExecutionContext`:

> ```
> private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  { 
>     button1.Text = await Task.Run(async delegate 
>     { 
>         string data = await DownloadAsync(); 
>         return Compute(data); 
>     });  
> }
> ```
>
> Here’s what my mental model tells me will happen with this code.  A
>   user clicks button1, causing the UI framework to invoke button1_Click
>   on the UI thread.  The code then kicks off a work item to run on the
>   ThreadPool (via Task.Run).  That work item starts some download work
>   and asynchronously waits for it to complete.  A subsequent work item
>   on the ThreadPool then does some compute-intensive operation on the
>   result of that download, and returns the result, causing the Task that
>   was being awaited on the UI thread to complete.  At that point, the UI
>   thread processes the remainder of this button1_Click method, storing
>   the result of the computation into the button1’s Text property.
>
> My expectation is valid if SynchronizationContext doesn’t flow as part
>   of ExecutionContext.  If it does flow, however, I will be sorely
>   disappointed.  Task.Run captures ExecutionContext when invoked, and
>   uses it to run the delegate passed to it.  That means that the UI
>   SynchronizationContext which was current when Task.Run was invoked
>   would flow into the Task and would be Current while invoking
>   DownloadAsync and awaiting the resulting task.  That then means that
>   the await will see the Current SynchronizationContext and Post the
>   remainder of asynchronous method as a continuation to run back on the
>   UI thread.  And that means my Compute method will very likely be
>   running on the UI thread, not on the ThreadPool, causing
>   responsiveness problems for my app.
>
> The story now gets a bit messier: ExecutionContext actually has two Capture methods, but 
>   only one of them is public.  The internal one (internal to mscorlib)
>   is the one used by most asynchronous functionality exposed from
>   mscorlib, and it optionally allows the caller to suppress the
>   capturing of SynchronizationContext as part of ExecutionContext;
>   corresponding to that, there’s also an internal overload of the Run
>   method that supports ignoring a SynchronizationContext that’s stored
>   in the ExecutionContext, in effect pretending one wasn’t captured
>   (this is, again, the overload used by most functionality in mscorlib).
>   What this means is that pretty much any asynchronous operation whose
>   core implementation resides in mscorlib won’t flow
>   SynchronizationContext as part of ExecutionContext, but any
>   asynchronous operation whose core implementation resides anywhere else
>   will flow SynchronizationContext as part of ExecutionContext.  I
>   previously mentioned that the “builders” for async methods were the
>   types responsible for flowing ExecutionContext in async methods, and
>   these builders do live in mscorlib, and they do use the internal
>   overloads… as such, SynchronizationContext is not flowed as part of
>   ExecutionContext across awaits (this, again, is separate from how task
>   awaiters support capturing the SynchronizationContext and Post’ing
>   back to it).   To help deal with the cases where ExecutionContext does
>   flow SynchronizationContext, the async method infrastructure tries to
>   ignore SynchronizationContexts set as Current due to being flowed.

However it isn't exactly clear to me *when* this might happen. It appears that it will happen when the public `ExecutionContext.Capture` method is used and the internal `Task.Run` overload that suppresses flowing `SynchronizationContext` with `ExecutionContext` is *not* used, but I don't know when that would be.

In my testing on .NET 4.5 `Task.Run` does not seem to flow the `SynchronizationContext` with the `ExecutionContext`:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Console.WriteLine("Click context:" + SynchronizationContext.Current);
    button1.Text = await Task.Run(async delegate {

        // In my tests this always returns false
        Console.WriteLine("SynchronizationContext was flowed: " + (SynchronizationContext.Current != null));

        string data = await DownloadAsync();
        return Compute(data);
    });
}
```

So my question is under what circumstances will `Compute()` be run on the UI context (blocking the UI thread) as discussed in the article?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> When does Task.Run flow SynchronizationContext with ExecutionContext?

Never.

The point of that article is that (the public API for) flowing `ExecutionContext` will flow `SynchronizationContext`. But `Task.Run` (and "pretty much any asynchronous operation whose core implementation resides in mscorlib") will never do this.

The paragraph starting with "My expectation is valid if" is hypothetical. He's describing what *would* happen if `Task.Run` use the public API for flowing `ExecutionContext`. This *would* cause problems *if* it did this. That's why it doesn't ever do this.