# Uploading async to Azure Blob Storage never returns

Tags: c#, azure, async-await, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to use the async methods to upload a file to Azure blob storage and then set its metadata, but the `UploadFromByteArrayAsync` method never returns.

I have the following code:

```
var connAzureBlob = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureBlobStorage"];    
var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connAzureBlob);
var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

var fileContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureBlobContainer"]);
if (!fileContainer.Exists())
{
    await fileContainer.CreateAsync();
    await fileContainer.SetPermissionsAsync(new BlobContainerPermissions {
                                                                             PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
                                                                         });
}

try
{
    var fileBlob = fileContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(documentId.ToString());
    await fileBlob.UploadFromByteArrayAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    Log.Info($"{nameof(SaveToBlobAsync)}: blob {documentId} uploaded.");

    await fileBlob.FetchAttributesAsync();
    fileBlob.Properties.ContentType = contentType;
    fileBlob.Metadata["..."] = "...";
    await fileBlob.SetMetadataAsync();
    Log.Info($"{nameof(SaveToBlobAsync)}: {documentId} - metadata saved.");
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    Log.Error($"{nameof(SaveToBlobAsync)}: An exception was thrown while saving a file to a blob: ", exception);
    throw;
}
```

Using the above code, I'd expect to see the following messages logged:

> SaveToBlobAsync: blob 123 uploaded.
>   SaveToBlobAsync: 123 - metadata saved.

But these never appear.

However, the blob does appear to be stored (I can view its contents using the [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/)) but the process doesn't seem to move to the next line (which would be the first logging message).

If I switch all the async calls for their non-async counterparts then the code works as expected.

Can anyone explain why `UploadFromByteArrayAsync` doesn't seem to return?

**Update:**
I thought I'd add some more information about the context, in case it helps.

This code is being called from a Web API method. The controller in question has no async code and does little else other than call a repository method. The repository method updates a SQL DB - again, all this is non-async code - before calling a class which interfaces with the blob storage.

This blob storage-facing class has non-async methods which do little else other than calling their async equivalents with either `.Wait()` or `.Result`.

In the case in question, the repository in the second stage is calling the non-async version, so the above code is essentially being called with `.Wait()`.

Until the above code, there are no other async calls in this HTTP request from the point where it enters the Web API's controller.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error is almost certainly further up your call stack, where some method is blocking on the returned task (e.g., `Task<T>.Result`, `Task.Wait`, etc.). This will deadlock if the thread being blocked is required for the task to complete.

[I explain this situation in full on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), but the gist of it is this:

- `await` by default will capture a "context" and use that to resume the `async` method.
- If this code is executed in an ASP.NET request context, this "context" is an ASP.NET `SynchronizationContext`; if this code is executed in a UI thread, this "context" is a UI `SynchronizationContext`.
- Both the ASP.NET `SynchronizationContext` and UI `SynchronizationContext` only allow one thread in them at a time.

Thus, when the calling code *blocks* on the returned `Task`, it is *holding* a thread within that context, preventing the `Task` from completing.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Stephen, though I'm not sure where this blocking could be occurring. I've added more info to OP in case it makes the situation clearer.

Comment: @awj: You said "In the case in question, the repository in the second stage is calling the non-async version, so the above code is essentially being called with .Wait()." - That's where the blocking is occurring.

Comment: Could you possibly explain _why_ I can't call my async method with `.Wait()`? I've used it in other places without problem, so why might it be a problem here?

Comment: @awj: Check out the blog post I linked to; it explains how `Wait` can cause deadlocks.

Comment: awj - unfortunately, you hit a known issue in the Storage Client that I am actively working to fix.  The problem is exactly what Stephen describes - in the Storage Client, we are calling Task.Wait() or Task.Result at a location where we may be in an ASP.NET or UI SyncronizationContext.  The bug fix should be in the next release.

Comment: If you need a temporary workaround, try calling UploadFromByteArrayAsync in a separate thread, or wrapping it in a Task.Run(), something like that.  As long as you're not in an ASP.NET/UI SyncronizationContext when you call into UploadFromByteArrayAsync(), it shouldn't deadlock.  This SO question explains more:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548389/when-does-task-run-flow-synchronizationcontext-with-executioncontext

Comment: @StephenCleary - What impact does `ConfigureAwait(false)` have? Is there a performance impact? What reasons are there for it not being the default?

Comment: @awj: [`ConfigureAwait(false)` avoids the context capture that happens by default](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html). The performance difference is negligible. Application code generally needs context, and library code generally prefers to avoid it; there's no universal "best" default.