# await Task doesn't capture Synchronization Context

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, synchronizationcontext, executioncontext

I am trying to play around with `ExecutionContext` and `SynchronizationContext`.

I am using WinForms and .NET Framework 4.5.

Here's my code

```cs
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var capturedExecutionContext = ExecutionContext.Capture();
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        ExecutionContext.Run(capturedExecutionContext, async (state) =>
        {
            // capturedSyncContext is not null
            var capturedSyncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;

            await Task.Delay(3000);

            SynchronizationContext.Current.Post((state) => {
                lblHelloWorld.Text = "Nice";
            }, null);

        }, null);
    });
}
```

`capturedSyncContext` is not `null` as expected because the `ExecutionContext` is already captured it.

However, after the await statement, `SynchronizationContext.Current` returns `null`.

I believe that, the `SynchronizationContext` should be captured when you await a Task awaiter.

So why `SynchronizationContext` is null in this case ?

Comment: Have you read Stephen Toub's excellent article about [ExecutionContext vs SynchronizationContext](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/executioncontext-vs-synchronizationcontext/)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When does Task.Run flow SynchronizationContext with ExecutionContext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548389/when-does-task-run-flow-synchronizationcontext-with-executioncontext)

Comment: That post was the reason makes me play around with Execution Context. Yes I understand that SyncContext does not flow with ExecutionContext when using Task.Run. However, I have explicitly capture the ExecutionContext before Task.Run. ExecutionContext is also CAPTURED SyncContext as well that's why the capturedSyncContext is not null